# How can I handle an event when pressed Start button (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

How can I make an event when pressed on Start button  (windows Phone) ?

**UPDATED**
If it is not possible, so how can I understand that user have pressed START button ?

Answer (score 7):

The Start and Search buttons themselves are reserved and do not generate events to third party applications.

Having said that, two events will be generated when the user pushes the start button:

1. A navigation event with [`NavigationMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationeventargs.navigationmode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) being `Forward` and [IsNavigationInitiator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationeventargs.isnavigationinitiator%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) being `false`
2. A [PhoneApplicationService.Deactivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.deactivated%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event

However you cannot cancel the navigation using either of these events and they can occur for other reasons (like pressing the search button).

Comment: So how can I understand that user have pressed START button ?

Comment: Read about Fast App Switching. This is not thesame as pressing the windows button because it can happen for other reasons but this is what will happen to your app when the start buttn is pressed

Comment: so where can I use the event PhoneApplicationService.Deactivated to understand that user have press go back button?