# Application_Deactivated and Application_Closing events are not triggering after launching ConnectionSettings Task in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am launching ConnectionSettings Task from Secondary tile.like

```
ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/Settings.xaml?Tile=miMobile", UriKind.Relative), NewTileData);
```

in Settings.xaml code is like

```
if ((Tile == "miMobile"))
    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-cellular:"));
```

once user changes the settings, based on that settings status I need to update secondary tile's image.

But once settings changed if I click Home button none of the events are triggering(Application_Deactivated,Application_Closing). 
How to handle Start button click event?

Thanks.

Comment: Ultimately, if your question is just how to handle the Start button's click event, then this is a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850221/how-can-i-handle-an-event-when-pressed-start-button-windows-phone . Check out the answer on this question, it should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you lhan16... I gone through the above article. If I click Start button on app MainPage, its triggering Application_Deactivated event. But in my scenario I am launching settings like                 await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-cellular:"));        So once the respective settings page launched and if I click Start button no event is raising :(